# How can the Starship booster stand vertically without falling over?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

How can the Starship booster stand vertically without falling over?

In my day to day experience, similar long objects (simple objects that can be easily found in thehouse) tend to fall easily with a slight touch or wind.

Can someone explain in simple terms how such a massive object does not fall either when standing or when it is moving (even if it is very slow) on a vehicle?

Comment: When it's being moved on a vehicle, I very much doubt that it contains fuel, so it is not all that massive.  You might ask why a strong wind doesn't blow it over.

Comment: Note that rockets are almost always securely attached to their launch mounts to stop them falling over. NASA is a fan of explosive bolts for this purpose.

Comment: A version of SpaceX's Starhopper did get blown over, at least partially (reports are conflicting), on 23 January 2019.

Answer (score 23):

Starships so far were simply bolted to the transport stand, I believe. Super Heavy doesn't have a skirt it could stand on (and Booster 4 in particular has 29 Raptors sticking out its bottom), so that is not really possible.

It looks like the Super Heavy transport stand has clamps to hold the booster in place:
[image: Super Heavy Transport Stand]

Comment: I am looking for fundamental reasons something like whether center of gravity is lower, if so why it is lower, how wind does not flip this huge structures etc.

Comment: If it's clamped down, then its 'center of gravity' is roughly at the center of the Earth.

Comment: @jrp consider the following: skyscrapers are similarly long objects, and also do not fall over easily.  They are attached to foundations, attached to the Earth.  Very similar to a booster, clamped to the foundation, attached to the Earth.  Now, you can ask about/consider the rigidity of the object in question, but in both of these cases, they are (functionally) a part of the earth below them and therefore do not tip.

Comment: @jrp One fundamental reason is the cube square law. Large objects don't behave like small objects; forces relative to the area (e.g, wind) scale with the square while the gravitational counter-force scales with the *cube* of the linear size. Now unfueled rockets have a very low density; but still: While two stacked empty soda cans can blow over from some moderate wind, the booster won't.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Obviously (it is moving, right?) the harness is not fixed to the ground, and the center of mass is considerably higher than the surface. It could tip over from a sufficient horizontal force. Why it doesn't, see my other comment.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica “the booster won't [blow over]” – I wouldn't count on it. Remember the Falcon Heavy center core from ArabSat-6A, which landed on the drone ship but later toppled over and was lost at sea, despite the sizeable landing legs and low CM due to the engines. To be wind-secure, fixing to the ground or something really heavy is necessary.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune  that would only be true if the entire structure were made of rigid unobtanium.  Try clamping any structure that has maximum shear and bending force limits and see how the C.M. matters

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well, it was [not only wind](https://www.space.com/spacex-loses-falcon-heavy-core-booster-at-sea.html): "As conditions worsened with 8- to 10-foot swells, the booster began to shift and ultimately was unable to remain upright." *Tilting* effects are scale invariant ;-).

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune: So, as the Earth rotates, in fact these clamped-down rockets _are_ tipping over!

Comment: @jrp: There are several structures at Starbase which are even higher than Super Heavy, for example the High Bay. There are structures which are both higher and skinnier than Super Heavy, for example the Launch Tower. There are even structures that are both higher and skinnier than Super Heavy, that significantly lean to one side, and are not anchored to the ground, in particular the Liebherr LR11350 "Frankencrane". It would help if you could explain why you have no problems with those structures or, say, the Statue of Liberty, the Eiffel Tower, the Burj Kalifa, or One World Trade Center.

Comment: Great question (I was just now wondering the same thing) and great answer (you heard it on that YouTube channel I also follow), thanks to both!

Answer (score 14):

We need to realize this is all in flux, as SpaceX is changing everything, sometimes daily.

BN3 and the other bits they built for Boosters were attached to manufacturing bases, with different attachment points.

BN3 is currently on a test stand that was designed to hold a Starship upper stage. They built an adapter for the Booster connection points.

For BN4, the one they installed all the engines on, there is a manufacturing stand that has 20 hold downs.

It has yet (as of this writing) to be rolled out to the pad. The new launch pad (as of this writing) is also not yet complete, so it is not certain exactly how that will work out.

There are a large number (20) of hold down clamps in the base to keep the booster connected. This is the current approach, if there is any constant here, it is change. So expect this to change.

(After I wrote this, they had rolled out the launch table and lifted it to the launch stand. And then they rolled out the BN4 booster to the pad.  No doubt by the time I finish writing this, they will have lifted the booster. Or flown it, who knows at this pace.)

Comment: It was rolled out today, actually. Literally just arrived. Which just proves your point: SpaceX moves fast!

Comment: @JörgWMittag How can you keep up?  It is so much fun!

Comment: My secret trick is to subscribe to NASASpaceflight YouTube notifications, not to watch the videos but just to read the titles :-D

Comment: I apologize.  They actually rolled the booster out today and I had yet to check up in the last few hours. As you noted, hard to keep up.  I love it.

Comment: I am looking for fundamental reasons something like whether center of gravity is lower, if so why it is lower, how wind does not flip this huge structures etc.

Comment: @jrp The fundamental reason is, big strong grippy things, nothing fancy like center of mass.

Comment: I think the answer got cut off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between mass (or density, depending on how you choose to look at it) and air resistance changes with size - very small objects like specks of dust can float around with almost no regard to gravity but very much affected by airflow, while larger (hourehold) objects are more affected by gravity than by airflow even though their density may be similar.  Very large objects such as rockets and buildings are influenced very little by airflow.

Comment: The relation between mass and air resistance changes with *shape*, not size. One Lego brick has mass M and air resistance (to a wind blowing sideways) R. A vertical stack of 100 bricks has mass 100M and air resistance 100R. But it should be obvious which structure is more stable!

Comment: Shape is significant (although in both cases we are considering a cylinder) but size most certainly does affect the importance of air resistance.  I haven’t included any calculations because it’s far from straightforward.  Look up Reynolds number for an insight if you’re not familiar with this.  The OP is specifically comparing the same shape at different scales, not different ratios of height to width.

Comment: To a first approximation, total wind force will scale with the square of dimension while mass will scale with the cube of dimension. However turning moment is force times distance, so the ratio of mass to overturning moment should remain roughly constant as the object gets larger.

Comment: On second thoughts though the turning moment caused by the mass will also scale with te size, so maybe larger objects are more stable after all.